# Adding file name as an additional column in a .txt file?

Tags: microsoft-excel, filenames

I have multiple .txt files that I am able to combine into one big .txt file.  What I'd like to do before combining is have each file name be a column inside the .txt file.  The filename is a date that is helpful when I eventually export the data into Excel.

When combining the .txt files, the file name does come in as a row...but not a column.

Thanks for any ideas or suggestions.

Comment: I would be helpful if you post your sample `input` and `output`.

Comment: Also what your OS is.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ perl -ne 'print "$ARGV,$_"' one two > three

$ cat three
one,aaa
one,bbb
two,ccc
two,ddd

$ cat one
aaa
bbb

$ cat two
ccc
ddd
```

Perl is included in most Linux distributions and is a free download on Windows.